# How to use workbook.saveas with automatic Overwrite

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

In this section of code, Excel ALWAYS prompts: "File already exists, do you want to overwrite?"

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xls.Workbooks.Add
fullFilePath = importFolderPath & "\" & "A.xlsx"

wb.SaveAs fullFilePath, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=True   

wb.Close(True)
```

Why does `db.SaveAs` always prompt me to overwrite existing file if I have `DisplayAlerts = False`?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To hide the prompt set `xls.DisplayAlerts = False`

`ConflictResolution` is not a `true` or `false` property, it should be `xlLocalSessionChanges`

**Note** that this has nothing to do with displaying the Overwrite prompt though!

```
Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    
xls.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = xls.Workbooks.Add
fullFilePath = importFolderPath & "\" & "A.xlsx"

wb.SaveAs fullFilePath, AccessMode:=xlExclusive,ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges    
wb.Close (True)
```

Comment: for some reason I'm still getting prompted to overwrite the file:                             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                            wb.SaveAs fullfilePath, ConflictResolution:=Excel.xlLocalSessionChanges

Comment: you need to tell the workbook you are working on to not display the alerts. I have updated the code above....Just look at the Application.DisplayAlerts  should be wb.Application.DisplayAlerts

Comment: thanks @Sorceri. I'll go with that and considered it answered. Thanks for your time ! -Bob

Comment: Does `wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = False` need to go below `Set wb = xls.Workbooks.Add`?

Comment: @JackDouglas - As written, you're correct - the `DisplayAlerts=False` line should be after setting the Workbook object.  However, you can set it globally by using just `Application.DisplayAlerts`.  And you should also probably change it back to True after you're done blocking Alerts.

Comment: +1 for use of wb.Application.DisplayAlerts.  I didn't know that existed.

Comment: @Sorceri your answer has many errors, please consider revising! **First** of all, ConflictResolution has nothing to do with the SaveAs overwrite prompt. (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198339(v=office.15).aspx) for details - it is about conflicts between multiple editors in a shared excel file.) **Second**, the `Application.DisplayAlerts` is a member of the `Application` object, **not** the `Workbook` object. So after creating the new instance of Excel application, use this command: `xls.DisplayAlerts = False`. (This is the real reason why OP's code didn't work.)

Comment: In your code, `wb.application.displayalerts` gives the same result as `xls.displayalerts`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835918(v=office.15).aspx) for details about `Applicaion` VS `Workbook.Application`. So although `wb.application` is technically correct, it is misleading in my opinion (as seen from some commenters suggesting the use of Application.Displayalerts insted...) But whichever you use, please move the code to the correct position, that is **after** creating the object itself. Now your code produces an error.

Comment: @vacip Good catch on the display alerts being before setting the object.  I removed the WB reference.  I do suggest you look at the saveas method of the workbook object.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx

Comment: @Sorceri thank you for willing to revisit this age-old thread! MSDN says about the SaveAs method's ConflictReslution: "Returns or sets the way conflicts are to be resolved whenever a **shared workbook is updated**." It is about workbooks with multiple editors. It has no effect on overwriting existing files.

Comment: In this specific question, OP creates a new instance of Excel (which is useless and is a bad idea, but anyway, he does). Because of this, you need to set the DisplayAlerts property for the new Excel instance like this: `xls.DisplayAlerts = False` right **after** the `Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` line, not before. Thank you for your patience and openness! It is important, as your answer is on the first page of Google for many searches. :)

Answer (score 29):

I recommend that before executing SaveAs, delete the file if it exists.

```
If Dir("f:ull\path\with\filename.xls") <> "" Then
    Kill "f:ull\path\with\filename.xls"
End If
```

It's easier than setting DisplayAlerts off and on, plus if DisplayAlerts remains off due to code crash, it can cause problems if you work with Excel in the same session.

Comment: Mind you that if the file is open in another process. it will throw an exception

Comment: Use some kind of an error handling to make sure DisplayAlerts is turned back on in case of an unexpected termination, like `On Error Goto Cleanup` or whatever way is available for error handling in the given context.

Comment: C# version:      `if (File.Exists(@"C:\test.txt")) {
  File.Delete(@"C:\test.txt");
}`

Answer (score 12):

To split the difference of opinion

I prefer:

```
   xls.DisplayAlerts = False    
   wb.SaveAs fullFilePath, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
   xls.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: `ConflictResolution` is not intended to be a true/false property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsaveconflictresolution

Comment: xls created with CreateObject.  It's a different instance of Excel... So the Application.DisplayAlerts is set in the **original** instance meanwhile the wb is saved in the second instance.  This answer shows setting the DisplayAlerts in the second instance which should work.

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it right, everything above is so confusing.

```
    Sub SaveAndClose()
    Dim wb1 As String
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    'this only works if the following equation is in C43 in sheet "data"
    '=LEFT(MID(CELL("filename",C41),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",C41))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",C41))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",C41))-1),75)
    'the vba equation has double quotes everywhere that is how you use a formula in vba.
'vba code recreates this incase it gets deleted by accident. 
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C43").ClearContents
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C43").Formula2R1C1 = _
            "=LEFT(MID(CELL(""filename"",R[-2]C),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",R[-2]C))+1, SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R[-2]C))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename"",R[-2]C))-1),75)"
        'https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/cell-reference-containing-file-name-changes-when-opening-second/m-p/2417030
    
    wb1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C43").Text
    If ThisWorkbook.Name = wb1 Then
    'MsgBox (wb1)
    Workbooks(wb1).Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
    
    End Sub
```

this will allow the spreadsheet to determine its own name and then only then can the sub run something against that name. this is so when you have multiple sheets running duplicate sheets but with different names you don't accidently close the wrong sheet. this is a huge win for CYA in my book.

This will also bypass the overwrite message too, you can have the code automatically run in the background on another workbook while you are working in a different workbook without being affected.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it appears unrelated.

Comment: @user10186832 it is very related as you can have multiple spreadsheets open with different names and you want to close and save your current workbook.