# Force yes for save over and save as macro free workbook

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

The macro I made saves a template workbook as two separate files. One is saved per test (Location1,2,3, or 4) then is used in another macro to use the data from each test. The Second is a raw data file kept for back up. Now the issue is every time I run the test per location and run this macro it ask me if I want to save over the previous test. How can I tell it to say yes with out asking. Same for the do i want to save this workbook as a macro free workbook. What do i have to put in my code and where should i put it? Any helps is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Solved Code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

   With Range("A30")
   .Value = Time
   .NumberFormat = "h-mm-ss AM/PM"
   End With

    Dim FileName    As String
    Dim FilePath    As String
    Dim FileDate    As String

    MyNote = "Is Cell 'B27' Overview Information" & SavePath & " Location1,2,3,or 4?"

    Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If Answer = vbYes Then

        FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test"
        FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("B27").Text

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName

        Dim FileCopyName    As String
        Dim FileCopyPath    As String
        Dim FileTime        As String

        FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Backup"
        FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("B27").Text
        FileTime = Sheets("Data").Range("A30").Text


        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName & FileTime & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

        MsgBox "File was saved!"
        MsgBox "Ready for Next Test, Please Exit."

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Else
       MsgBox "File was not saved, Please Use Location_1,2,3or,4 Durring SIG ATM Test"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before you try and save.  Remember to turn in back to True after you've saved.

Comment: Will that automatically say yes for both saves?

Comment: It should do providing you put it before the first save.  I'm looking at @MatthewD answer - I've never seen that method so it may work better.

Comment: Worked! I knew it was something simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ConflictResolution should be xlLocalSessionChanges to not see the prompt

```
ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
```

from

[How to use workbook.saveas with automatic Overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634453/how-to-use-workbook-saveas-with-automatic-overwrite)

Comment: This is incorrect. `ConflictReslution` deals with conflicts over shared workbooks, not the overwrite prompts, as is stated in the linked answers.