# Excel 2013 - Cannot paste cell value in Save As Dialog box

Tags: excel

I'm trying to save documents called "Client Advice - " *then value of cell=A1 which has a dropdown of clients*... I cannot copy and paste this value into the Save As Dialog box and I have tried multiple workbooks and have restarted both Excel and the computer

Is there either a way to fix this please? I'd rather not have to type hundreds of client names when the information is already there...

-A

Answer (score 0):

How about a macro?

See here : [How to use workbook.saveas with automatic Overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634453/how-to-use-workbook-saveas-with-automatic-overwrite)

```
Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    
xls.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = xls.Workbooks.Add
fullFilePath = importFolderPath & "\" & "A.xlsx"

wb.SaveAs fullFilePath, AccessMode:=xlExclusive,ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges    
wb.Close (True)
```

And then you would edit this line

> fullFilePath = importFolderPath & "\" & "A.xlsx"

So that it has your cell with its value in there

Comment: Hi rib, I've tried macros to save based on a cell value before and have encountered a couple issues. One being that this is workbook is for colleagues to use so the path will not work, the other issue I have is that Excel wants to export the file as a 2003 version of Excel which destroys my formulae and macros, making my workbook useless.....

It seems the formulae you gave just automatically overwrites the file though?????

Comment: I'm also getting runtime errors for your formula :(