# VB script to ignore dialog boxes

Tags: excel, vba

My code fetches data from a DWH and proceeds to save a specific page with new data as a pdf file. My intention is to Windows Scheduled Task to open the file weekly so it generates a new file with new data.

The issue is that when i run it, at the end, it prompts me with a dialog box about already existing file in the location i want to save to, which seems to interfere with WST abilities. The VB script has a path with a file name in it + adds current day into the name.

I am using Excel 2016 for Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Just check if the file already exists - and if yes, delete it. Or, if you don't want to delete it, add a unique suffix to the filename (eg `myfile (2).xlsx`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use workbook.saveas with automatic Overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634453/how-to-use-workbook-saveas-with-automatic-overwrite)