# Convert Excel To Exe File Using VB6

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

Hi guys i need a little bit of help. I have the following code in VB6 that i use to run my excel file. I compile the code in the VB6 userform into an exe file and when i open the vb6 file it automatically runs the excel file

```vb
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWkb As Object
    Dim xlWkbName As String
    Dim xlWkbPath As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")

    xlWkbName = "GCR Client Invoice.xlsm"

    xlWkbPath = App.Path

    Set xlWkb = xlApp.WorkBooks.Open(xlWkbPath & "\" & xlWkbName)


    Set xlWkb = Nothing

    xlApp.application.quit
    
    Unload Me

    End Sub
```

After that i compile both the VB6 file and my Excel file into an exe file that can be installed on any computer.

The challenge i am now facing is that having installed the exe file, i am able to run my excel file but on closing my excel userform i get this notification that there is another excel file with the same name stored at the same location and that do i want to replace it as seen in the screen shot attached.

[image: Screen Notification]

I would be grateful if i can get any help as to how to deal with this challenge. Thanks

Comment: Does the code try to save the excel file on close ? What happens on form unload?

Comment: My Excel VBA code automatically saves the file on close. With my VB6 code as seen above it does not have a save script but rather a quit command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634453/how-to-use-workbook-saveas-with-automatic-overwrite

Comment: @ John Eason - where do i place the solution you shared in the link? Do i place it in the workbook close event?

Comment: @KobbyAdom I have to admit that it's years since I last used vba (or VB6 for that matter) and I think I've lost most of the code I had which used it so someone else will have to answer that one. I just googled 'vba automatic overwrite' which I'd remembered using in the past and it led me to that SO posting.